# What are the SDK's in C/C++ (Open source) I can use to develop Netconf client and Server

Tags: snmp, net-snmp, ietf-netmod-yang, ietf-netconf

I am looking to develop a client  and agent using any open source netconf frameworks. Can anyone please suggest an open source library which is similar like How NetSNMP is there for SNMP.

Answer (score 0):

There is nice C++ library called POCO that implements NETCONF: https://www.appinf.com/docs/poco-2008.2/NetconfUserGuide.html

There is also https://github.com/CESNET/libnetconf